# How twitter changes url without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, twitter, routes, url-routing, single-page-application

Recently I've noticed that if we are at our profile view/url (`http://twitter.com/profileName`) and click on one of our tweets to see its details on popup, the url changes (`http://twitter.com/profileName/status/statusId`) without reloading the page (no `#` in url used).

With further investigation, I've noticed that `window.history` changes, from:

```
{ title: "profileName (@profileName) | Twitter" }
```

to:

```
{ inOverlay: true, rollbackCount: 1 }
```

I'm currently working on own Single Page App stack, and stuck on writing own router - looking forward for alternatives against currently trending `#` usage and thought that understanding this twitter hack can help me a bit.

Comment: I saw that thread earlier, but wasn't sure if twitter uses same mechanism (so I've created this thread) - anyway, it can be closed now. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use the [HISTORY API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API):

```
window.history.pushState("", "", '/newpage');
```

Reference: https://blog.twitter.com/2012/implementing-pushstate-for-twittercom

Comment: thanks for reference link!

Comment: You are welcome :)